# How do I get documents where a specific field exists/does not exists in Firebase Cloud Firestore?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

In Firebase Cloud Firestore, I have "user_goals" in collections and goals may be a predefined goal (master_id: "XXXX") or a custom goal (no "master_id" key)

In JavaScript, I need to write two functions, one to get all predefined goals and other to get all custom goals.

I have got some workaround to get custom goals by setting "master_id" as "" empty string and able to get as below:

```
db.collection('user_goals')
    .where('challenge_id', '==', '')  // workaround works
    .get()
```

Still this is not the correct way, I continued to use this for predefined goals where it has a "master_id" as below

```
db.collection('user_goals')
    .where('challenge_id', '<', '')  // this workaround
    .where('challenge_id', '>', '')  // is not working
    .get()
```

Since Firestore has no "!=" operator, I need to use "<" and ">" operator but still no success.

**Question: Ignoring these workarounds, what is the preferred way to get docs by checking whether a specific field exists or does not exists?**

Comment: You can't query for something that doesn't exist in Firestore.  A field needs to exist in order for a Firestore index to be aware of it.

Comment: Is this still true in 2021? Really unfortunate.

Comment: hello there, can you explain your question further?

Answer (score 76):

As @Emile Moureau solution. I prefer

```
.orderBy(`field`)
```

To query documents with the field exists. Since it will work with any type of data with any value even for `null`.

But as @Doug Stevenson said:

> You can't query for something that doesn't exist in Firestore. A field needs to exist in order for a Firestore index to be aware of it.

You can't query for documents without the field. At least for now.

Comment: I'm coming to firestore from mongo and reading this makes me sad

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. This matches any field type. I just tested with string, number, timestamp, map.

Comment: In python firebase_admin this is `.order_by('field')`.

Answer (score 50):

The preferred way to get docs where a specified field exists is to use the:

```
.orderBy(fieldPath)
```

As specified in the [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data#order_and_limit_data):

[image]

Thus the answer provided by @hisoft is valid. I just decided to provide the official source, as the question was for the preferred way.

Comment: I Wanted to get documents where particular field doesn't exist. Is it possible ?

Answer (score 13):

Firestore is an [indexed database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/index-overview). For each field in a document, that document is inserted into that field's index [as appropriate based on your configuration](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/index-overview#automatic_indexing). If a document doesn't contain a particular field (like `challenge_id`) it will **not** appear in that field's index and will be omitted from queries on that field. Normally, because of the way Firestore is designed, queries should read an index in one continuous sweep. Prior to the introduction of the `!=` and `not-in` operators, this meant you couldn't exclude particular values as this would require jumping over sections of an index. This limitation is still encountered when trying to use exclusive ranges (`v<2 || v>4`) in a single query.

Field values are sorted according to the [Realtime Database sort order](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#orderbychild) except that the results can be sorted by multiple fields when duplicates are encountered instead of just the document's ID.

**Firestore Value Sort Order**

| Priority | Sorted Values | Priority | Sorted Values |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | `null` | 6 | *strings* |
| 2 | `false` | 7 | *DocumentReference* |
| 3 | `true` | 8 | *GeoPoint* |
| 4 | *numbers* | 9 | *arrays* |
| 5 | *Timestamp* | 10 | *maps* |

#### Inequality `!=`/`<>`

*This section documents how inequalities worked prior to the release of the `!=` and `not-in` operators in [Sep 2020](https://firebase.google.com/support/releases#sdk_releases_154). [See the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#not_equal_) on how to use these operators. The following section will be left for historical purposes.*

To perform an inequality query on Firestore, you must rework your query so that it can be read by reading from Firestore's indexes. For an inequality, this is done by using two queries - one for values less than the `equality` and another for values greater than the equality.

As a trivial example, let's say I wanted the numbers that aren't equal to 3.

```
const someNumbersThatAreNotThree = someNumbers.filter(n => n !== 3)
```

can be written as

```
const someNumbersThatAreNotThree = [
   ...someNumbers.filter(n => n < 3),
   ...someNumbers.filter(n => n > 3)
];
```

Applying this to Firestore, you can convert this ([formerly](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#not_equal_)) incorrect query:

```
const docsWithChallengeID = await colRef
  .where('challenge_id', '!=', '')
  .get()
  .then(querySnapshot => querySnapshot.docs);
```

into these two queries and merge their results:

```
const docsWithChallengeID = await Promise.all([
  colRef
    .orderBy('challenge_id')
    .endBefore('')
    .get()
    .then(querySnapshot => querySnapshot.docs),
  colRef
    .orderBy('challenge_id')
    .startAfter('')
    .get()
    .then(querySnapshot => querySnapshot.docs),
]).then(results => results.flat());
```

**Important Note:** The requesting user must be able to read **all** the documents that would match the queries to not get a permissions error.

#### Missing/Undefined Fields

Simply put, in Firestore, if a field doesn't appear in a document, that document won't appear in that field's index. This is in contrast to the Realtime Database where omitted fields had a value of `null`.

Because of the nature of NoSQL databases where the schema you are working with might change leaving your older documents with missing fields, you might need a solution to "patch your database". To do this, you would iterate over your collection and add the new field to the documents where it is missing.

To avoid permissions errors, it is best to make these adjustments using the Admin SDK with a service account, but you can do this using a regular SDK using a user with the appropriate read/write access to your database.

This function loops through your whole query, and is intended to be executed **once**.

```js
async function addDefaultValueForField(queryRef, fieldName, defaultFieldValue, pageSize = 100) {
  let checkedCount = 0, pageCount = 1;
  const initFieldPromises = [], newData = { [fieldName]: defaultFieldValue };

  // get first page of results
  console.log(`Fetching page ${pageCount}...`);
  let querySnapshot = await queryRef
    .limit(pageSize)
    .get();

  // while page has data, parse documents
  while (!querySnapshot.empty) {
    // for fetching the next page
    let lastSnapshot = undefined;

    // for each document in this page, add the field as needed
    querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
      if (doc.get(fieldName) === undefined) {
        const addFieldPromise = doc.ref.update(newData)
          .then(
            () => ({ success: true, ref: doc.ref }),
            (error) => ({ success: false, ref: doc.ref, error }) // trap errors for later analysis
          );

        initFieldPromises.push(addFieldPromise);
      }

      lastSnapshot = doc;
    });

    checkedCount += querySnapshot.size;
    pageCount++;

    // fetch next page of results
    console.log(`Fetching page ${pageCount}... (${checkedCount} documents checked so far, ${initFieldPromises.length} need initialization)`);
    querySnapshot = await queryRef
      .limit(pageSize)
      .startAfter(lastSnapshot)
      .get();
  }

  console.log(`Finished searching documents. Waiting for writes to complete...`);

  // wait for all writes to resolve
  const initFieldResults = await Promise.all(initFieldPromises);

  console.log(`Finished`);

  // count & sort results
  let initializedCount = 0, errored = [];
  initFieldResults.forEach((res) => {
    if (res.success) {
      initializedCount++;
    } else {
      errored.push(res);
    }
  });

  const results = {
    attemptedCount: initFieldResults.length,
    checkedCount,
    errored,
    erroredCount: errored.length,
    initializedCount
  };

  console.log([
    `From ${results.checkedCount} documents, ${results.attemptedCount} needed the "${fieldName}" field added.`,
    results.attemptedCount == 0
      ? ""
      : ` ${results.initializedCount} were successfully updated and ${results.erroredCount} failed.`
  ].join(""));

  const errorCountByCode = errored.reduce((counters, result) => {
    const code = result.error.code || "unknown";
    counters[code] = (counters[code] || 0) + 1;
    return counters;
  }, {});
  console.log("Errors by reported code:", errorCountByCode);

  return results;
}
```

You would then apply changes using:

```
const goalsQuery = firebase.firestore()
  .collection("user_goals");

addDefaultValueForField(goalsQuery, "challenge_id", "")
  .catch((err) => console.error("failed to patch collection with new default value", err));
```

The above function could also be tweaked to allow the default value to be calculated based on the document's other fields:

```
let getUpdateData;
if (typeof defaultFieldValue === "function") {
  getUpdateData = (doc) => ({ [fieldName]: defaultFieldValue(doc) });
} else {
  const updateData = { [fieldName]: defaultFieldValue };
  getUpdateData = () => updateData;
}

/* ... later ... */
const addFieldPromise = doc.ref.update(getUpdateData(doc))
```

Answer (score 9):

The solution I use is:

Use: `.where('field', '>', ''),`

Where "field" is the field we are looking for!

Comment: as per the question, will this query works if the field doesn't exist in firestore?

Comment: This query will work but it will only return objects with this field!

Comment: Has someone verified this and knows if this is true?

Comment: Hi, I tried this solution, but it's only work with some fields.. Anyone knows why ?

Comment: works for me on a field containing text other than empty string afaik

Comment: If you want to include empty strings, do this: `.where('foo', '>=', '')`. However, this only seems to work with strings.

Answer (score 1):

As you correctly state, it is not possible to filter based on `!=`.  If possible, I would add an extra field to define the goal type.  It is possible to use `!=` in security rules, along with various string comparison methods, so you can enforce the correct goal type, based on your `challenge_id` format.

### Specify the goal type

Create a `type` field and filter based on this field.

`type: master` or `type: custom` and search `.where('type', '==', 'master')` or search for custom.

### Flag custom goals

Create a `customGoal` field which can be `true` or `false`.

`customGoal: true` and search `.where('customGoal', '==', true)` or false (as required).

## Update

It **is** now possible to perform a != query in Cloud Firestore

Comment: Good. So, I can maintain it as two fields 1. `challenge_id` and 2. `is_custom` as `true` or `false`. And I can filter by `where('is_custom', '==', false)

Comment: I have very limited exposure to NoSQL databases. Is just this Firestore have very limited functionalities or all NoSQL dbs in general?

Comment: It depends on the noSQL database.  MongoDB has a `$ne` which returns documents which are _not equal_ to a value.

Comment: @RamBabuS Mongo can also query if something exists and is not equal to. I have not hit any crazy limitations like this with Mongo

Comment: Following an update to Cloud Firestore (a while back), it is now possible to perform a != query.

Comment: It is possible to use !=, but only if the field exists

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#not_equal_

Use the not equal (!=) operator to return documents where the given field exists and does not match the comparison value.

Answer (score 0):

Firestore does pick up on boolean, which is a thing! and can be `orderBy`'d.

So often, like now, for this, I add this into the array-pushing from `onSnapshot` or `get`, use `.get().then(` for dev...

```
if (this.props.auth !== undefined) {
  if (community && community.place_name) {
    const sc =
      community.place_name && community.place_name.split(",")[1];
      const splitComma = sc ? sc : false
    if (community.splitComma !== splitComma) {
      firebase
        .firestore()
        .collection("communities")
        .doc(community.id)
        .update({ splitComma });
    }
    const sc2 =
      community.place_name && community.place_name.split(",")[2];
      const splitComma2 =sc2 ? sc2 : false
    console.log(splitComma2);
    if (community.splitComma2 !== splitComma2) {
      firebase
        .firestore()
        .collection("communities")
        .doc(community.id)
        .update({
          splitComma2
        });
    }
  }
```

This way, I can query with `orderBy` instead of `where`

```
browseCommunities = (paginate, cities) => {
  const collection = firebase.firestore().collection("communities");
    const query =
      cities === 1 //countries
        ? collection.where("splitComma2", "==", false) //without a second comma
        : cities //cities
        ? collection
            .where("splitComma2", ">", "")
            .orderBy("splitComma2", "desc") //has at least two
        : collection.orderBy("members", "desc");
  var shot = null;
  if (!paginate) {
    shot = query.limit(10);
  } else if (paginate === "undo") {
    shot = query.startAfter(this.state.undoCommunity).limit(10);
  } else if (paginate === "last") {
    shot = query.endBefore(this.state.lastCommunity).limitToLast(10);
  }
  shot &&
    shot.onSnapshot(
      (querySnapshot) => {
        let p = 0;
        let browsedCommunities = [];
        if (querySnapshot.empty) {
          this.setState({
            [nuller]: null
          });
        }
        querySnapshot.docs.forEach((doc) => {
          p++;
          if (doc.exists) {
            var community = doc.data();
            community.id = doc.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not an ideal solution, but here is my workaround when a field does not exist:

```
let user_goals = await db.collection('user_goals').get()
user_goals.forEach(goal => {
  let data = goal.data()
  if(!Object.keys(data).includes(challenge_id)){
    //Perform your task here
  }
})
```

Note that it would impact your read counts a lot so only use this if you have small collection or can afford the reads.

Comment: I think `contains` must be `includes` in the code above.

Answer (score 0):

Well, as you know, you can not query based on a field that doesn't exist. so the best way could be to store that data in different collections.

if you want to keep all the data in the same collection then you will end up adding one more field in every data like.
"a": true  {consumes 3 bytes}
or "a": "b" {consumes 4 bytes}

so if the data count per retrieval is 100 then each user will incur
3 * 100 bytes => 300 Bytes.

if i have 1000 users per day then it will increase usage by
300 KB approx per day.

it may not be a big deal for some startups but it may lead to heavy usage in the future.

Answer (score -2):

```
const fieldName = 'someField';
db.collectionGroup('students')
    .get()
    .then((querySnapshot) => {
      querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        const documentData = doc.data();
        if (!documentData[fieldName]) {
          console.log(doc.id);
        }
      });
    });
```

You can use this code to find and print the documents where the field does not exist