# 'orderBy' on a potentially non-existent field skips the doc entirely

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

A brief background: I have an `onCreate` cloud function which, after some async tasks, assigns a `createdAt` timestamp to the recently created doc. This function failed a few times which resulted in some of my docs not having this `createdAt` property at all -- so no `null` values but rather an absent field.

Now, as I'm paginating through the collection using something along the lines of

```
_ref.orderBy('createdAt', 'desc')
    .startAfter(cursorSnapshot)    // <-- most probably not playing a role here?
    .limit(200)
```

I'd expect the docs with a missing timestamp at (either) end of the ordered collection. Instead I noticed they were **skipped**.

Is this the desired behavior? [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58490387/8160318) claims that

> one cannot query for documents for non-existent fields.

If so, how do I re-include the skipped docs?

*P.S.: I've fixed my cloud function so this should not happen anymore but I'm stunned these docs were actually skipped.*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Queries work from one or more indexes, and only return documents that are present in the indexes. If a document doesn't have a field that you order/filter on, it won't be in that index, and won't be returned by the query.

The only solution is to ensure the documents have a marker/default value for the field.