# Firestore: Check if the value in the document exist

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore

I have this query in my Firestore UI adapter

```
query = collectionReference.whereEqualTo("City", FirestoreConstants.CURRENT_CITY);
```

and the query above fetches all the document which is equal to the current city.
Now what I want to achieve is, if the FirestoreConstants.CURRENT_CITY does not exist in my documents, I just want to fetch all the data in my Firestore DB.

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49579693/how-do-i-get-documents-where-a-specific-field-exists-does-not-exists-in-firebase

If the field does NOT exist, you simply CANT search for it.

Comment: you can also `get()` your current query then in `addOnSuccessListener` check if your snapshot are empty then get all results in that reference

Comment: `if FirestoreConstants.CURRENT_CITY does not exist in my documents`, query will be empty. So check if query is empty and if it is empty, call another query to fetch all documents.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this, you need to check if your query returns some results or not. If it returns, use those documents, otherwise, get all documents within the collection, as explained in the following lines of code:

```
query.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            QuerySnapshot snapshot = task.getResult();
            if (!snapshot.isEmpty()) {
                for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                    Log.d(TAG, document.getId() + " => " + document.getData());
                }
            } else {
                collectionReference.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> t) {
                        if (t.isSuccessful()) {
                            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : t.getResult()) {
                                Log.d(TAG, document.getId() + " => " + document.getData());
                            }
                        } else {
                            Log.d(TAG, "Error getting documents: ", task.getException());
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "Error getting documents: ", task.getException());
        }
    }
});
```