# How can I query for uncompleted ToDo items and the past 24 hours of completed ToDo items together?

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore

I have a ToDo item that a user can use a checkbox to toggle on whether they have completed it or not. The completionDate attribute is assigned the current date and it is updated on Firestore. If the user unchecks the value, it is assigned back to nil.

```
struct ToDo: Identifiable, Codable {
    @DocumentID var id: String?
    var title: String = ""
    var completionDate: Date?
    var userId: String?
}
```

I want to query for all the uncompleted ToDo items aswell as the completed ToDo items that were checked by the user in the past 24 hours. The query that I have so far does not deal with the uncompleted tasks as I can not query for a nil value.

```
let query = db.collection("tasks")
            .whereField("completedDate", isGreaterThan: Date().advanced(by: TimeInterval(-86400)))
            .whereField("userId", isEqualTo: userId)
```

This way the snapshot listener will not retrieve old completed ToDo items and allow the user a period of 24 hours of changes before it is gone.

### Edit 1

This is a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nGJjk.png) of a ToDo in the tasks collection from the firebase console. This would be an example of a ToDo that is incomplete. It does not have a completionDate field so when it is fetched and mapped to a ToDo object the attribute is nil.

Comment: What is the problem with the code you shared? Is there an error message?

Comment: It fetches the completed ToDos that have been completed in the past 24 hours however it does not fetch the ToDos that have not been completed

Comment: What value in a ToDo document identifies it as not having been completed?

Comment: I followed Peter Friese’s ToDo list app YouTube series and originally it was just a Boolean that was either true or false but I realised that I need a way to make sure old ToDos which are completed are not involved in the initial fetch and the way of phasing out the old completed ToDos was to have a completed date attribute instead of the Boolean. If the date exists then it is completed if nil then it is not. Now I can query for ToDos that are completed in the last 24 hours but I can’t seem to figure out how to include ToDos that are incomplete

Comment: `.whereField("completedDate", isEqualTo: nil)`?

Comment: When adding that where clause to the query, I get the following error `'nil' is not compatible with expected argument type 'Any'`

Comment: To make sure: do your uncompleted tasks have a `completedDate` field with a value of `nil`? Can you edit your question to show a screenshot of one of them from the Firebase/Firestore console?

Comment: I have provided a screenshot of the collection that stores the ToDos. It does not have a field for completionDate. Are you suggesting that I don't save the value as a timestamp but a string?

Comment: There is no way to filter in a query for documents that **don't** have a specific field, as those documents won't appear in an index on that field. Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58490387/209103