# What is the best way to store a ToDo on Firestore?

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I recently followed the [build a to do list app](https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PLl-K7zZEsYLkTjfUJvjiPZ14F5c81uDuN) with SwiftUI and Firestore run by Peter Friese on YouTube. The ToDos had a boolean completed attribute to indicate whether or not they are complete and they are fetched with a snapshot listener.

Below is an example of a ToDo item that is stored and retrieved from my Firestore collection.

```
struct ToDo: Identifiable, Codable {
    @DocumentID var id: String?
    var title: String = ""
    var completionDate: Date?
    var userId: String?
}
```

I wanted to achieve the following functionality:

- Incomplete ToDos would be fetched
- Complete ToDos in the last 24 hours would be fetched

Due to the time functionality I swapped the Boolean attribute for a completion date that gets updated every time the user checks or unchecks whether or not they have complete a ToDo.

Regarding [my last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73207519/how-can-i-query-for-uncompleted-todo-items-and-the-past-24-hours-of-completed-to), I discovered that I cannot query for ToDos that have a nil value nor can I make this an OR statement to retrieve the completed ToDos in the last 24 hours in one query.

Is it possible to have the above functionality with one query and one snapshot listener?

### Edit 1

Below is an extract from my data model class that fetches my tasks from my firestore collection. The comments are what I want the query below to reflect.

```
import Foundation
import Firebase

class TaskData: ObservableObject {
    @Published var tasks: [Task] = []
    
    private var db = Firestore.firestore()
    private var listenerRegistration: ListenerRegistration?
    
    init() {
        subscribe()
    }
    
    deinit {
        unsubscribe()
    }
    
    func subscribe() {
        guard let userId = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }
                
        if listenerRegistration != nil {
            unsubscribe()
        }
        
        /*
         complete = true
         completedDate = Date.now - 24 hours
         
         OR
         
         completed = false
         */
        
        let query = db.collection("tasks")
            .whereField("userId", isEqualTo: userId)
        
        listenerRegistration = query.addSnapshotListener { querySnapshot, error in
            guard let documents = querySnapshot?.documents else {
                print("No documents in 'tasks' collection")
                return
            }
            
            self.tasks = documents.compactMap { queryDocumentSnapshot in
                try? queryDocumentSnapshot.data(as: Task.self)
            }
        }
    }
    
    func unsubscribe() {
        if listenerRegistration != nil {
            listenerRegistration?.remove()
            listenerRegistration = nil
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can certainly perform two queries and combine the results.  What's the problem you're finding with that?  Have you tried something that doesn't work the way you want?

Comment: Would having two queries mean I would have to have two snapshot listeners? Would something like this not be possible with one query and one listener?

Comment: I wonder why you don't store the `completed` state (as a `Bool`), *and* the `completionDate`. By updating both when the user toggles the completion state, you should be able to meet your needs.

Comment: @PeterFriese I would love to know how to do this, would this be possible with one query and one listener? Because I can’t see how, I understand that it can be done with two queries and two listeners, is this approach what you are suggesting? At the end of the day I always want to opt for the most elegant solution here. I’m inclined to go with Franks answer but would welcome alternative solutions here because I feel there would be an elegant solution involving the Boolean attribute you talk about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you default the `completionDate` to a timestamp very far in the future, you can get all documents that were completed in the past 24h and that are not yet completed with a single query on that field.

```
todoRef.whereField("completionDate", isGreaterThan: timestampOfYesterday)
```

In your application code, you will then have to identify the documents with the default `completionDate` and mark them as incomplete in your UI.

Comment: And the alternative to this would be to do something like what Doug mentioned where I could have two queries and two listeners?

Comment: Yes, which is what the answers I linked to [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73207519/how-can-i-query-for-uncompleted-todo-items-and-the-past-24-hours-of-completed-to) about the same problem already said.

Comment: Hey @JackRogers. Did you get a chance to try the approach I mentioned in my answer?

Comment: Hey mate, I am halfway through implementation. I was curious to the solution Peter briefly teased as well :D