# Firestore - getting documents fields if included in an array

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

I'm new in node and Firestore, so apologize if this is trivial.
In my nodejs app I create dynamically an array of items, i.e.
`items = ["jan","may","aug"]`.
In Firestore I've a document that contains a couple of fields:

```
jan: "12"
mar: "2"
may: "4"
```

[image: firestore db]

I would like with a single query in Firestore select only the elements in Firestore that are also defined in items:

```
jan: "12"
may: "4"
```

This is just an example, the sizes of both of the arrays are much bigger, and I'd like to avoid to use loops if possible.

I had a look at https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#array_membership
but didn't find what I was looking for.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you edit your question to show either the JSON of your document (as text), or a screenshot of the document from the Firebase console?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the goal or the problem here. If you want to query the document you've shared, that'd be something like `db.collection("posts").where("jan", "==", "12").where("may", "==", "4")`. Is that not working for you?

Comment: not really, sorry if I'm bad in explaining. the node app is not aware of the values 12 and 4. It only knows the months defined in the items variable. So I can't use a where clause with may == 4 for example.
I'd need something like db.collection("posts").where(field in items).
Does it make sense?

Comment: To get documents where a specific field exists, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49579693/how-do-i-get-documents-where-a-specific-field-exists-does-not-exists-in-firebase. If you run into problems with multiple fields at some point, you *may* need to add an extra map to your document specifically for this query: `monthsBooked: { jan: true, mar: true, may: true}`. With such a map in place you can use equality conditions for the query: `db.collection("posts").where("monthsBooked.jan", "==", true).where("monthsBooked.may", "==", true)`.