# snapshor.foreach() not called Firebase Cloud Firestore v9

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, vuejs3

I was working on deleting documents whose value(Timestamp) is passed 2 hours from now. I got to call the onSnapshot() but the snapshot.foreach() is not called. Checked by console.log; called1 shows on the console but called2 does not. I was wondering why it is not called to delete documents.

```
onMounted(() => {
    const itemsCollectionRef = collection(db, "Bookings");
    const cutoffTimestamp = Date.now() - 2 * 60 * 60 * 1000; // Two hours ago
    const oldItemsQuery = query(
      itemsCollectionRef,
      where("Date", "<", cutoffTimestamp)
    );

    onSnapshot(oldItemsQuery, (snapshot) => {
      console.log('called1');
      snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        // Delete the document
        console.log('called2');
        db.collection("Bookings").doc(doc.id).delete();
      });
    });
  })
```

Comment: You seem to have it right.. snapshot could be empty, try finding out what is being returned? Have you tried adding the error callback to see if your query is failing? e.g. `onSnapshot(oldItemsQuery, (snapshot) => {}, (error)=>console.log(error))`. Also this line will fail; `db.collection("Bookings").doc(doc.id).delete();` if you're using the modular api stick with the modular syntax (i.e. use doc(db, `/Bookings/${doc.id}`) etc...).

Answer (score 0):

In Cloud Firestore, each field value is [sorted in the index according to its value](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68265825/3068190). In particular, number values are sorted earlier in the value index than `Timestamp` values. Your query of `where("Date", "<", cutoffTimestamp)` will always return 0 results because it is trying to find `Timestamp` values that are smaller than the given number.

To correct this, you need to pass in either a `Timestamp` or `Date` value to your `where()` filter. If you choose to use a `Date` object, it will be [serialized as a Timestamp object automatically by the SDK](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/blob/68b79e1a065173d6caac9c7bd11a472b2bb49854/packages/firestore/src/lite-api/user_data_reader.ts#L852-L857). This allows you to use what you are comfortable with.

```
const cutoffTimestamp = Timestamp.fromMillis(Date.now() - 2 * 60 * 60 * 1000); // Two hours ago
// or const cutoffDate = new Date(Date.now() - 2 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
const oldItemsQuery = query(
  itemsCollectionRef,
  where("Date", "<", cutoffTimestamp)
);
```

Additionally, instead of logging "called1" and "called2", try the following:

```
onSnapshot(oldItemsQuery, (snapshot) => {
  console.log(`Found ${snapshot.size} documents older than 2h`);
  snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
    // Delete the document
    console.log(`Requesting #${doc.id} be deleted…`);
    deleteDoc(doc.ref) // <-- Modern Firebase SDK equivalent of ref.delete()
      .then(() => console.log(`Deleted #${doc.id} successfully.`))
      .catch((err) => console.error(`Failed to delete #${doc.id}`, err));
  });
});
```